# Load type annotations from stub file at runtime

Tags: python, mypy

I have two files, `vector3.py` and `vector3.pyi`. One is the source and one is the stub. They are not partial, so mypy can load it. However, how can I write a file that imports `vector3` but also loads `vector3.pyi`? I would like to have `__annotations__` defined for every object in the imported module.

Basic example:

```py
# vector3.py
class Vector3:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vector3(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y, self.z + other.z)
```

```py
# vector3.pyi
class Vector3:
    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float, z: float) -> None: ...
    def __add__(self, other: Vector3) -> Vector3: ...
```

I have tried using `mypy.parse` to load the stub file, but I don't understand how to use the `MypyFile` class from `mypy.nodes` to parse the stub file.

Comment: Why can't you put the type annotations directly into the `.py` file?

Comment: I would like to keep the stubs and the source separate for readability. Please don't suggest to merge them together because I have tried that and I feel its too messy for a project that's already 9 months in.